# Java Get Constructor Created in a Different Class

Tags: java, object, junit, constructor, subclass

I have the constructor MappaFermi() that creates an object from the class Settore with the attributes coordinataX=10,coordinataY=8 and settoreNome=Nome.ALIENI

```
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    public MappaFermi() {
        new Alieni(10,8);
    }
 }
```

This is the class Settore

```
public class Settore {
        private Nome settoreNome;
        private char letteraX;
        private final int coordinataX;
        private final int coordinataY;

    public Settore (int coordinataX, int coordinataY){
        this.coordinataX=coordinataX;
        this.coordinataY=coordinataY;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return coordinataX;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return coordinataY;
    }
    public Nome getSettoreNome() {
        return settoreNome;
    }
    public void setSettoreNome(Nome settoreNome) {
        this.settoreNome = settoreNome;
    }

}
```

This is the enum Nome for the attribute settoreNome

```
  public enum Nome {
        SICURO, PERICOLOSO, SCIALUPPA, ALIENI, UMANI
    }
```

This is the subclass ALIENI from the class Settore that sets settoreNome to Nome.ALIENI

```
public class Alieni extends Settore {
    public Alieni(int coordinataX, int coordinataY) {
        super(coordinataX, coordinataY);
        setSettoreNome(Nome.ALIENI);
    }
}
```

This is the class Mappa that is a superclass from MappaFermi but i don't think it is involved with my question

```
public class Mappa {
    private Name mappaName;
    private final Settore [][] settore;
    private int Matrice [][];
    private static final int X=23;
    private static final int Y=14;

    public Mappa (){
        settore = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                settore[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
    }

    public Name getMappaName() {
        return mappaName;
    }

    public void setMappaName(Name mappaName) {
        this.mappaName = mappaName;
    }
}
```

Ok, here is my question, when i create an object MappaFermi this creates at the same time an object Settore, what i wanna do is to use the method getSettoreNome() from the class Settore for that object. I know i should start by creating a local variable mappa = new MappaFermi() but from that i don't know how to get the Settore(10,8) with the settoreNome=Nome.ALIENI that is created in new MappaFermi().

```
public class MappaFermiTest {
    @Test
    public void testSettoreAlieni(){
        Mappa mappa = new MappaFermi();
        Settore settore = ??????;
        assertEquals(Nome.ALIENI, settore.getSettoreNome());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Ok, here is my question, when i create an object MappaFermi this creates at the same time an object Settore" - yes, but then it doesn't *do* anything with the newly created object. Why is it creating it? Should it be part of the state of the class? I suspect you want a field rather than a local variable. It's hard to tell as you haven't explained what you're really trying to achieve. (There's also *far* more code here than you need in order to demonstrate the problem...)

Comment: As a best practice, try to keep your code in english. That's the standard.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have put all the code because otherwise it's pointed out that something is missing, i'm doing a test to see that when i run MappaFermi() it creates a Settore(10,8) with settoreNome=Nome.ALIENI so i thought a way to do that was using the method getSettoreNome() from Settore(10,8) and comparing the settoreName with Nome.Alieni

Comment: @marcosguerra: You should work on create a short but *complete* program. I didn't suggest posting incomplete code - I suggested only posting what is required to demonstrate the problem. That doesn't have to be all the code you're working on; it doesn't have to look much like your real code at all. But in your `MappaFermi` constructor you're creating an object and then basically doing nothing with it - *why* are you doing that? What purpose does that servce in your code? Surely it's only useful if you keep a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

In `MappaFermi`, you are not storing the Alieni created?

```
public MappaFermi() {
    new Alieni(10,8); // You are just creating, not assigning to anything
}
```

So there isn't a way for you to get this `Alieni` thingy.

You have to declare it as a member of MappaFermi, and create a getter function for getting it.

e.g.

```
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {

    private Alieni alieni;

    public MappaFermi() {
        alieni = new Alieni(10,8);
    }

    public Alieni getAlieni() { return alieni; }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, i have a question because in the actual code of MappaFermi() i have more objects to create of the class Settore so, if after alieni=new Alieni(10,8); i write new Alieni(10,9); when i want to call getAlieni() it's gonna return the last new Alieni(10,9) or I can select which object i want to return?

Comment: @marcosguerra It's your code, so you get to decide what you want to return. It's just a matter of how you write it.